# primefaces show contextmenu on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

I've searched a lot but I can't hit the answer, my problem is that I have a datatable with a context menu. On desktop I have no problem, it shows up on right click, but on mobile devices I can't get it to work: when I tap and hold the row it selects the nearest text and shows up the browser's context menu.

I've tried a lot of things:

- Adding a css class style:

```js
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

and the implementation as:

```js
<p:dataTable id="lista" widgetVar="lista" var="unElem" ...>
    <p:column headerText="Column 1" styleClass="noselect">
        <h:outputText value="#{unElem.codigo}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:contextMenu for="lista" id="context" model="#{view.modeloMenuContextual}"/>
```

- Searching on the web about the "event" attribute of the p:contextMenu and found that the default event is "contextmenu", so if you need other events you can add them space separated. The other event I found was "click", but I don't need it

  ```js
  <p:contextMenu model="#{view.modeloMenuContextual}" event="click contextmenu"/>
  ```
- Searching in the official documentation (web and pdf) (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/)
- Searching in Primefaces' code in github (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces)

I'm working with PrimeFaces 6.2

Hope anybody can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: I think I got this working on 6.1 some time ago at least on chrome and firefox on android. Can you state which combinations you tried? I might be able to look into this over the weekend

Comment: Hi there @Kukeltje! thanks for the answer. I tried just few events: "tapandhold", "clickandhold" and "hold". Maybe I should keep trying with this, but maybe I'll never find going that way. That was the reason I asked. Best

Comment: hahaha, sorry, meant combination of browsers and os

Comment: no problem, haha. I tried in chrome and safari on iphone and on chrome on android